# How to read value after special character in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have giving value in my Input tag

I have a first Value :

> "United State"

then after my Values are coming like :

> "United State; United Kingdom"

For Third time value is like :

> "United State; United Kingdom; United Nation"

How to read latest value in input tag which is in second and third case coming after `;` and first case coming directly.

I am using plain javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the **[`split() method`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** to divide the string then retrieve the last item from the result like :

```
var result_arr = "United State; United Kingdom; United Nation".split(';');

console.log(result_arr[result_arr.length-1]);
//Or
console.log(result_arr.pop());
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var result_arr = "United State; United Kingdom; United Nation".split(';');
console.log(result_arr.pop());
```

Comment: But if the value is just "United State" No `;` then what will be result. Ok let me test

Comment: It will be _United State_

Answer (score 0):

Use `split(";");`

> The split() method is used to split a string into an array of
>   substrings, and returns the new array.
>
> Tip: If an empty string ("") is used as the separator, the string is
>   split between each character.
>
> Note: The split() method does not change the original string.

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for something like this

```
const values = document.querySelector('input.foo').value.split(';');
const lastValue = values.slice(-1);
```

with **ES6**

```
const values = document.querySelector('input.foo').value.split(';');
const [firstValue, ...rest] = values;
const lastValue = rest.slice(-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
var countries = "United State; United Kingdom";
var afterFirst = countries.substr(str.indexOf(";") + 1);
```